# how to display local IP using a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ip, ipconfig

So far I have the following in my batch file:

```
%comspec% /c ipconfig | find "IPv4" > %HOMEPATH%\desktop\MyIP.txt
%comspec% /c start notepad %HOMEPATH%\desktop\MyIP.txt
```

However, when I run the batch file, MyIP.txt is empty when displayed.

On the other hand, when I run each line one after another from Windows-Start search field it works.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Works fine from a batch file here.

Couple suggestions:

- Try wrapping the HOMEPATH file paths in quotes to make up for any potential spaces:
  `%comspec% /c ipconfig | find "IPv4" > "%HOMEPATH%\desktop\MyIP.txt"`
- Ensure you are running the batch file as a user who has a valid homepath and desktop (and not as say, the "System" account).
- Try `echo %HOMEPATH%` alone in another batch file and launch it the same way, check the output to see if %HOMEPATH% expands to what you are expecting (tip add "pause" to the end of the batch to have it wait for you to hit a key).

Comment: +1 for spaces; would most likely fail on an XP machine ("documents and settings" being part of %HOMEPATH%) without quotes.

Comment: when I just run %HOMEPATH% in a batch file it shows me the following:
\Users\60021601
Putting C:\ in front or adding quotes around the destination doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Is your user name really "60021601"?  What does `echo %homepath%`show if you just run it manually at a command prompt? Have you tried running it as a different user?

Comment: To be honest, my main priority is to display the IP in a notepad window and I would like to avoid saving the txt file on the desktop.    Is this possible?

Comment: @techie007 yes, that is my user name.  Running as a different user shows a correct name as well.

Comment: also, sometimes I need to run the batch file twice in order to create MyIP.txt on the desktop.  The first time I run the batch sometimes doesn't produce MyIP.txt.  However, MyIp.txt produced by the batch is always empty.  Very strange.

Comment: @panhandel yeah and if on an XP machine it'd also fail because an XP machine doesn't say IPv4 in the ipconfig output, it says "IP Address". but really he should be doing some basic troubleshooting, like making paths absolute for a start. and I never bother saying compspec. cmd runs fine and if it didn't, i'd know. Maybe on somebody else's system that complexity might help for portability, but not for mine or for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Save the below given code as batch file in system32 folder.
For Windows 7 keep batch file in  C:\Windows\System32 .

```
@echo.
@echo                         IP INFORMATION
@echo                         By:Aswin Sha

@ipconfig/all | find "Subnet Mask"
@ipconfig/all | find "IPv4" 
@ipconfig/all | find "Default Gateway"
@ipconfig/all | find "Host Name"
@ipconfig/all | find "DNS Suffix Search List"
@ipconfig/all | find "Physical Address"
@ipconfig/all | find "DHCP Enabled"
@ipconfig/all | find "DHCP Server"
@ping 127.0.0.1
@echo.
@pause
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with Windows 10:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims={}, " %%A in ('wmic nicconfig get ipaddress') do for /f "tokens=1" %%B in ("%%~A") do set "IP=%%~B"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%j in ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| findstr Reply') do (
    set localip=%%j
)
echo Public IP is: %IP%
echo Local  IP is: %localip:~11%
```

It returns both public and private IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use a batch file? As per your requirements, the following code saved as **GetIP.vbs** and executed will launch Notepad and print your IP address(es) in it *without* saving as a text file first:

```
Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled=TRUE", , 48)
For Each objItem In colItems
    If InStr(objItem.IPAddress(0), ":") = 0 Then
        strIP = "Description: " & objItem.Description & vbCR & "IP Address : " & objItem.IPAddress(0) & vbNewLine
    End If
Next
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "Notepad"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
WshShell.SendKeys strIP
```

Comment: wow, what a great script!  working nicely but is it possible to tweak it to display only IPv4 addresses (one per line) and omit IPv6?  To take it one step further, it would even be better if it would specify the adapter type (LAN or WiFi) for each IP.  Lastly, will this work for XP and 7?  I wish I knew VBScript to make these changes.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Have edited the script to include the network adapter description as well as print only IPv4 addresses. It should work fine on XP+ (on XP IPv6 isn't installed by default), but I checked only in Win7.

Comment: i just tested the new version and it's showing the description now but if I am connected with both wifi and lan, it only shows wifi info.  Is there a way to show both?

Comment: Did the old version handle both correctly? I can't test your scenario at present. Can you try deleting `WHERE IPEnabled=TRUE` from the SELECT statement and see if that helps?